# Determining Formula Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Guys, I am using SQL Server 2000 and executing the sp_columns stored procedure to get a layout of my table. One of my fields is a formula field and my question is, how can I determine this through sp_columns? sp_columns does not seem to show this information.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dump the results of sp_columns to a temp table, and then add on the [ColumnProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226011(SQL.80).aspx) function to the results of that...

```
create table #results(
    TABLE_QUALIFIER sysname,
    TABLE_OWNER sysname,
    TABLE_NAME sysname,
    COLUMN_NAME sysname,
    DATA_TYPE smallint,
    TYPE_NAME sysname,
    PRECISION int,
    LENGTH int,
    SCALE smallint,
    RADIX smallint,
    NULLABLE smallint,
    REMARKS varchar(254),
    COLUMN_DEF nvarchar(4000),
    SQL_DATA_TYPE smallint,
    SQL_DATETIME_SUB smallint,
    CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH int,
    ORDINAL_POSITION int,
    IS_NULLABLE varchar(254),
    SS_DATA_TYPE tinyint)

insert  #results
exec sp_columns 'MyTable'

select  IsComputed = ColumnProperty(object_id(table_owner + '.' + table_name), column_name, 'IsComputed'),
        *
from    #results
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM syscolumns where id IN(
SELECT ID FROM sysobjects where name = 'My Table' and xtype ='U')
and IsComputed = 1
```

Raj